# Cannot create SQL Encryption Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to encrypt a backup for our new financial database. This is a brand new database so absolutely nothing had been previously set up. I'm working in  Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Been trying to follow MSDN, but it is not helpful, the pages just link to each other and end up in a self referential circle. Painful!

So, here is what I have done so far.

1. Logged in as sa
2. `sp_configure 'show advanced', 1`
3. `sp_configure 'EKM provider enabled', 1`
4. Created a certificate

   ```
   CREATE CERTIFICATE fooBackup 
      ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '#########'
      WITH SUBJECT = '### Server Backup Key', 
      EXPIRY_DATE = '20201031';
   GO
   ```
5. Checked that it exists with `SELECT * FROM sys.certificates` (It does exist!)
6. Tried to create a Encryption Key

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
       WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
       ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE fooBackup;
   GO
   ```

And this is where I get stuck. I receive the following error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>
> Cannot find the certificate 'fooBackup', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I've tried granting ALTER and CONTROL permissions on symmetric and asymmetric keys as shown here http://bit.ly/1OcbYyt and as I said, I'm logged in as SA. I can see that it exists. I just... am lost.

Any help for someone struggling his way through SQL would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed to run that, `backup` is a reserved keyword, I'm getting a syntax error when trying to run your code.

Comment: I believe you need to create your `[Backup]` certificate in `master` and not the user database. however based on your details I get an error when creating the encryption key `Cannot use certificate 'Backup', because its private key is not present or it is not protected by the database master key. SQL Server requires the ability to automatically access the private key of the certificate used for this operation`. Your certificate should be protected by the database master key of master and not a password

Comment: sorry, it was called ###Backup where ### is a company name. Have edited question to reflect

Comment: Unfortunately, changing your example to be `###Backup` is likely to cause confusion also, since the `#` prefix is usually used in SQL server to signify temporary objects.

Comment: aah right forgive an inexperienced SQL'er. have switched to fooBackup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this to work by creating a certificate using the master key instead of its own password.

The steps for this are:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '5tr0ngP@ssW0rd'
GO

OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '5tr0ngP@ssW0rd'

CREATE CERTIFICATE MyDBcert 
  WITH SUBJECT = 'The Cert For MyDB';
GO

USE MyDB;
GO

CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
  WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 
  ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE MyDBcert;
GO
```

With this done, you are free to use the certificate to encrypt your database backups.